# Checkpointing with EventProcessorClient with the new .NET SDK Azure.Messaging.EventHubs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-sdk-.net

**How to periodically save a checkpoint after a certain time or a specified number of events with the [new Azure SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/2019-11/dotnet.html)?**

The sample only uses an ["InMemoryPartitionManager"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs_5.0.0-preview.5/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/README.md) which doesn't save the current state.

Then there is an [BlobPartitionManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/7b43dfe1efc2c10031d1ce87437531eaafe9e3a7/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.CheckpointStore.Blobs) which saves the state in blob storage, but it seems like it saves the state for each event which can get pretty expensive if the there are a lot of events.

Neither on the EventProcessorClient nor the BlobPartitionManager could I find any option to only save in a certain interval.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "BlobPartitionManager" is a good solution. It just stores a json file which is less than 1kb in azure blob storage after read operation. So I think it will not take up too much space of your storage. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) to know more about the price of storage blob, I think it is not too expensive to store something so small.

Comment: Thought the same and went for it. But the problem is not the stored data which is indead very small, but the amount of requests. It seems that it's doing a write after each recieved event and that brings the cost only for wrting to 130$ assuming 10 requests per second.